# Rejected job offer, how to return and ask for it

Tags: job-change

So, approximately 3.5 months ago I applied for and was offered a job at a large Tech Consultancy firm.

I decided to reject the offer at the time because the timing wasn't right.

The two senior people who interviewed me both telephoned me on separate occasions to try and convince me to take the job. I still didn't take it.

Out of the two, the most senior (Director) told me to connect on LinkedIn and that if I ever changed my mind that I should contact him. He said this kind of thing does happen.

I have now decided that I want to take this job, wholeheartedly!

Now, I am planning on mailing this guy through LinkedIn and ask if the job is still available.

Considering this guy is fairly senior, he won't want to read a long mail from me. But, at the same time I don't want to send a few lines and seem blasé about the whole thing.

Basically without boring him I want him to know that I have thought long and hard and really want the job!

Thanks.

Comment: Euh, what's your question? From the text of your post, it looks like you've already worked out what to do and how to do it - that's good, so it doesn't look as if you need any advice from us.

Comment: You're overthinking this. He said "if I ever changed my mind that I should contact him". You've changed your mind. Contact him.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]. Could you please [edit] your question to explain exactly what your problem is, and what solution you are trying to find? As-is, I can't figure out what exactly you're asking about. Are you trying to get someone to draft a sample e-mail for you? Are you wondering what an appropriate way to greet someone over linked in is? Are you asking what sorts of things to put in the letter? Please take a look at our [help] and [edit] your question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you prettymuch know what you want to do. How about a quick email asking for a followup chat - that'll be both brief and yet still serious about taking it forward, e.g.

> "Hi, (THEIR NAME HERE),
>
> I've been thinking long and hard about the job offer you made earlier
>   this year, and I've come to the conclusion it would probably be a good
>   move for me. If the position is still open, can we have a chat to
>   discuss the specifics?
>
> Regards,
>
> (YOUR NAME)"

Comment: The OP already has the offer. The only specifics the OP needs to discuss is the start date once the OP gets it confirmed that the position is open :) Aside from that quibble, it's a good email and I am giving you a +1 for it :)

Comment: I see where you are coming from - I was thinking it might seem presumptuous to assume the offer is open indefinitely, but I'm not strongly attached to that bit of the email either ;)